# Vue.js call method in the data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to vue.js and I want to call a method in the data so something like this:

```
data() {
        return {
            title: capitalizeFirstLetter('title'),
        };
    },
```

and my vue mixin which I imported to my main.js

```
Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    capitalizeFirstLetter(str) {
        return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
    }    
  }
})
```

but this doesnt work, I cant call `capitalizeFirstLetter` in the data. Is it possible to call a method in data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `this`

```
title: this.capitalizeFirstLetter('title'),
```

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure that you have registered the `mixin` in the component using mixin `property` in component.

After that you can access `capitalizeFirstLetter` method defined inside the mixin using `this.capitalizeFirstLetter`

**Working fiddle**

```js
const myMixin = {
  methods: {
    capitalizeFirstLetter(str) {
      return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mixins: [myMixin],
  data() {
    return {
      title: this.capitalizeFirstLetter('title'),
    };
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ title }}
</div>
```